# Replace all characters except one at given index

Tags: ruby

I already know how to replace a character at a given index, but I am looking to replace every character **except** the one at the index given.

For example, I have the string `"011010010"` and want to replace every character with `"0"`, except the first occurrence of `"1"`. I use `String#index("1")` to find the index of the first `"1"`, but from there, how would I go about changing the string to `"010000000"`?

Comment: Are you always dealing with "binary" strings? Are the strings always the same length?

Comment: Yes, I will always be dealing with binary strings. The strings will not always be the same length.

Comment: And are you always resetting them to zeros?

Comment: Yes, everything except the first `1` should become a zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace all the ones with zeros and then change the character you want to keep:

```
test = "011010010"
testIndex = test.index("1")
test.gsub!("1", "0")
test[testIndex] =  "1"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "011010010"
str[/0*1/].ljust(str.size,'0')
  #=> "010000000"
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a new string with all `0` values, of the same length of the original string, and then replacing the first index with a `1`:

```
str = "011010010"
first_one = str.index("1")

str = "0" * str.length
str[first_one] = "1"

puts str
#=> 010000000
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks :) I literally had this exact idea and got it to work 10 or so seconds before your post!

Answer (score 1):

```
flag = false
"011010010".gsub(/./){|s| (flag ? "0" : s).tap{flag = true if s == "1"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test = "011010010"
test.sub(/(0*1)(.*)/) { $1 << '0'*$2.length }
#⇒ "010000000"

test =~ /1/ && $` << '1' << '0'*$'.length || test # C'`mon parser
#⇒ "010000000"
```

Comment: @sawa I did paste the wrong attempt, thanks for pointing it out. Fixed.

Comment: You have a more serious problem. Run only the second one in isolation. Hint :( sad :{ not sad

Comment: @sawa, Yes, got it. Fixed with proper function (`match` instead of `sub`.)

Comment: @sawa I doubt I see any way to do it better without the necessity to involve the second matching. The latter would be slower. `'1'` ⇒ `$&` won’t make it any better as well. Am I missing smth obvious?

Comment: Have you read my hint? Just change `()` in your original to `{}`.

Comment: @sawa I am afraid I don’t get this one.

Comment: The reason the second code in your original (before the edit) did not work was because you used ``$` ``, etc as arguments to `sub`, which are evaluated before the regex match. You should have let  the `sub` take a block, and put them there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that, changing only characters after the first match:

```
str = "010010110"
first_occurence = str.index('1')
results = "#{str[0..first_occurence]}#{str[first_occurence..-1].gsub('1','0')}"
```

I assume there is some clever regexp for this, but not sure what that would be.